# Clone git repo to a Shared Mac OS X (folder) from Windows

Tags: macos, remote-access, git-clone, git-pull, git-remote

Clone git repo to a Shared Mac OS X (folder) from Windows

I am not able to clone a git repository in a shared folder over LAN, do let me know if anyone can help here

```
Cloning into '\\<ip address>\Demo\Demo_1\Demo_Test'...
POST git-upload-pack (152 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (190 bytes)
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.        
remote: Counting objects:  33% (1/3)        
remote: Counting objects:  66% (2/3)        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3)        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.        
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0        
Receiving objects:  33% (1/3)
Receiving objects:  66% (2/3)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
error: unable to write file <ip address>/Demo/Demo_1/Demo_Test/.git/objects/pack/5kjserkj343lkjl2k34nsdfjlks.pack: Permission denied
fatal: cannot store pack file
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Read write permission already granted for the shared folder to administrator, Mac OS user, everyone, staff

Tried chmod recursive too for the root folder

Comment: Check how it's mounted, it's possible that the mount was configured incorrectly thus flatenning the permissions or ignoring them.

Comment: I am able to browse using file explorer of windows by writing the //ip-address/.git/objects/pack/ of the macbook and from here i am also able to create new file, modify existing file etc. but while git "git pull/clone etc " tries to write in the .git/objects/pack/ folder it gives error

Comment: And what about sudo git?

Comment: unfortunately it gives the same error :(

Comment: It looks like the location you are trying to write to doesn't support linking like the Mac and Linux filesystems support, do you know the source filesystem of the remote folder? (NFS and SMB are only the remote connection protocol).